# Calling Different Function Based on Config

Tags: python, function, import

I'm trying to build a framework that takes in a file with data and depending on the name of the file calls a different function to transform that data. I can handle all the mapping parts, so far I just have a yaml config that maps file patterns to a schema string that represents the file that contains the function (function can have the same name) I need to call. Here's what my structure looks like so far:

map.yaml:

```
file/path/1: transform1
file/path/2: transform2
file/path/3: transform3
```

Then I have a folder `transformers` with the transformation files:

- transform1.py
- transform2.py
- transform3.py

and they each have a function `transform` that takes the data as an argument and returns transformed data.

But even though I can use the yaml to get the correct string, I'm struggling to import the correct function. Here's what I've tried:

```
import transformers
def get_mapper(file):
  map_file = get_map_file(file) # this just transforms "file/path/1" into "transform1"
  return getattr(transformers, map_file)
```

But this throws error `AttributeError: module 'transformers' has no attribute 'transform1'`

The only way I can even get this to import even if I know the name in advance is to `from transformers import transform1` and then I can call `transform1.transform(data)`.

I'm open to solving this problem by adding classes, using decorators (I believe at a previous company we used that approach but it may not have been exactly like this), reformatting pretty much anything, although do keep in mind there will be 100+ different transformers which is why I did want to separate them into their own files rather than jamming them all into a single file where I'd be able to import them easier using getattr. I'm just not sure what the best practice for doing this is, and I'm struggling to find people asking this question although it seems like a relatively common task people would want to do.

Comment: You might be looking for [`importlib.import_module`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module) to deal with dynamic import, e.g. `from transformers import transform1 as module` can be done using `module = importlib.import_module('.transform1', 'transformers')`.  Note the `.` prefixing `transform1` to denote relative import, and if relative import from `transformers` must be enforced, ensure that the `.` is added (e.g. `importlib.import_module('.' + name, 'transformers')`.

Comment: Oh interesting that did it, I'm a bit confused why the need for the dot though since if I were importing it just as the name as in "from transformers import transform1" I didn't need any dot. Thanks!

Comment: If you had referred to the link I had included, you would have came across this sentence - "If the name is specified in relative terms, then the *package* argument must be set to the name of the package which is to act as the anchor for resolving the package name", note how you wanted `transformers` being the anchor for resolving the package name, thus the `.` specifies the import relative to `transformers`, otherwise the resolution will be done in absolute terms (which will fail unless the absolute `transformers.transform1` is specified).